# div changes moving direction when reaches border

Tags: javascript

I got problem with my code. I got a div(id - ball) which is moving to the top and left by default. Then, when it reaches a top of wrapper block (with id = field) the "ball" should change its moving direction. BUT it changes everything wrong. Here is my code. Dont laugh at my code skills, i'm newbie...:)
I actually understand why the ball continues to fly in wrong direction, but I havent any ideas how I can fix it, so please help me:)

```
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');


     var timer = setInterval(function ()
        {
            var posTop = ball.offsetTop;
            var posLeft = ball.offsetLeft;
            var ballPositionX = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(ball). left) ;
            var ballPositionY = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(ball). top);

            ball.style.top = --posTop + 'px';
            ball.style.left = ++posLeft + 'px';

                if( ballPositionX <= 0 )
                {
                    ball.style.top = --posTop + 'px';
                }
                if( ballPositionX <= 550 )
                {
                    ball.style.top = ++posTop + 'px';
                }
                if( ballPositionY <= 0 )
                {
                    ball.style.left = ++posLeft + 'px';
                }
                if( ballPositionY >= 1000 )
                {
                    ball.style.left = --posLeft + 'px';
                }
        }, 10);
```

and HTML is here:

```
<div class="field" id="field">
        <div id="here"></div>
        <div class="ball" id="ball"></div>
        <div class="desk" id="desk"></div>
    </div>
```

and here is CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.field{
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 650px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: aliceblue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ball{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: green;
    -webkit-border: 5px double silver;
    -moz-border: 5px double silver;
    -ms-border: 5px double silver;
    -o-border: 5px double silver;
    border: 5px double silver;
    position: absolute;
    top: 550px;
    left: 0;
}

.desk{
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    background: darkblue;
    -webkit-border: 3px double silver;
    -moz-border: 3px double silver;
    -ms-border: 3px double silver;
    -o-border: 3px double silver;
    border: 3px double silver;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 610px;
    left: 10px;
}

.blocks{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background: brown;
    text-align: center;
    color: lightcoral;
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/n3skLuo3/

Comment: can you provide demo please?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: yes, of course. link is in the bottom of my question.

Comment: _the "ball" should change its moving direction._ what are you trying to achieve? like the ball should start moving along the sides of the container? can you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: i'm trying to realize a ball which is bouncing of the fields borders. by the way, my final target is an arkanoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to store direction along x/y-axes ( two binary flags representing 'increment/decrement_x/y_coordinate' suffice) that have to change upon reflection at one of the field edges.

```
var ball  = document.getElementById('ball');
var field = document.getElementById('field');
var d_x = 1.0;
var d_y = 1.0;
var h_ball  = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(ball).height);
var w_ball  = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(ball).width);
var h_field = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(field).height);
var w_field = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(field).width);

ball.style.left = '200px';
ball.style.top  = '200px';

var timer = setInterval(function ()
        {
            var posTop  = ball.offsetTop;
            var posLeft = ball.offsetLeft;
            var ballPositionX = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(ball). left) ;
            var ballPositionY = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(ball). top);

            if ( ballPositionX <= 0 )                 { d_x =  1.0;  }
            if ( ballPositionX >= w_field - w_ball )  { d_x = -1.0; }
            if ( ballPositionY <= 0 )                 { d_y =  1.0;  }
            if ( ballPositionY >= h_field - h_ball )  { d_y = -1.0;  }

            ball.style.top  = (posTop  + d_y) + 'px';
            ball.style.left = (posLeft + d_x) + 'px';
        }, 10);
```

`d_x/y` in the code above represent the coordinate change per time step. Weight and scale these with the coordinates and the length of your speed vector.

[Live demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3skLuo3/7/)

Comment: maybe canvas would be a great tool to solve this problem, but my task to code this program without it :c

Comment: No canvas needed. The version in the fiddle should get you started.